# Suppose events $A$ and $B$ are such that $P(A)=0.6$ and $P(B)=0.7$, how do we answer the following questions about $P(A\cap B)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose events $A$ and $B$ are such that $P(A)=0.6$ and $P(B)=0.7$, how do we answer the following questions about $P(A\cap B)$?

$1.$ Is it possible that $P(A\cap B)=0.1$? I think this is impossible. We know that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)=1.3-P(A\cup B)$, then $P(A\cup B)=1.2$ which is impossible, but is my understanding wrong?

$2. $ Is it possible that $P(A\cap B)=0.63$? Same procedure,$P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)=1.3-P(A\cup B)$, then $P(A\cup B)=0.67$, which may be possible? I feel this $0.63$ is odd to my calculation.

$3.$ What is the largest possible value of $P(A\cap B)$? I think this is when $A$ is fully included in $B$. Thus the largest is $0.6$.

Could someone clear my confusion?

Comment: Your answers to 2 and 3 contradict each other.

Comment: Let $A$ be a segment of length $0.6$, and $B$ a segment of length $0.7$.  Imagine placing these segments on the line appropriately to each of your questions.  E.g., can you place the segments so that the overlap has length $P(A \cap B) = 0.63$?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ the only events?

Comment: The question does not clarify, so I suppose we can't assume $A$ and $B$ are the only events.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're correct. If $P(A \cap B)=0.1$ then $P(A\cup B)=1.2$ which is impossible
2. This is impossible as well. It must always be the case that $P(A \cap B) \le P(A)$
3. Correct. Again, $P(A \cap B) \le P(A)$ and also $P(A \cap B) \le P(B)$, so greatest possible value is 0.6